# How to have DIV boxes listed horizontally

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a horizontal website, where all the objects inside it will be either half height or quarter height. There will also be a horizontal scroll bar. Boxes inside the big box sit next to each other to fill the space. See picture below for reference.

http://i62.tinypic.com/303k7ec.jpg

I have tried to make something like this in JsFiddle but it doesn't fill free spaces. [DMEO](http://jsfiddle.net/9922871h/)

My code:

```
.section {
    position:relative;
    width: auto;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#101010;
}
.boxHalf {
    margin: 2px;
    width:200px;
    height: 200px;
    background:red;
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline;
}
.boxHalf {
    position:relatives;
    margin: 2px;
    width:200px;
    height: 200px;
    background:red;
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline;
}
.box2{
    position:relatives;
    margin: 2px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline;
}
.scrolls {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    height: 200px;
    white-space:nowrap
}
```

Any idea to make something like the image ? For example when there are two small boxes, next to each other, they must go over each other to fill the free space and boxes stay tightly. like in the picture where 4 small boxes take the space of 1 big box.

Comment: I guess you are looking for [floats](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)

Comment: Floats may solve the problem, but for something that really looks like the image, I guess some positioning controls by absolutely positioning the boxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give a negative margin to each child div. Increase the negative margin if you want to make the gap invisible.

```
.scrolls > div{
   margin-left: -5px;
}
```

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/a_incarnati/9922871h/2/

Comment: Thats it. Its what I have been looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `float:left;`

Here is a jsfiddle: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5ffr6r97/)

Comment: Float left will break the layout. Try it applied to his jsfiddle. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a whitespace bug with `inline-block`.

The easiest solution is to apply `font-size: 0` to the parent container.

```
.section {
    position:relative;
    width: auto;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#101010;
    font-size: 0;
}
```

You will then need to re-apply any font-sizes within that. 
There are other methods to fix this issue including comments and removing whitespace. 
See [this article](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for your post, but it doesnt solve to problem, the boxes does not fill the space. for example two small boxes show go over each other. like the picture

Answer (score 0):

You can use floats to position the boxes, although for a more complicated layout you'll have to absolutely position the elements on the section.

Here's a link the the fiddle that I made for this: http://jsfiddle.net/arnellebalane/byvvfwn2/1/

The boxes have the following common style:

```
.box {
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**EDIT**

To make the smaller boxes stack on top of each other, I added the following rule:

```
.quarter + .quarter:nth-of-type(odd) {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: -100px;
}
```

This will make every other smaller box that is preceeded by another smaller bos (make sense?) go under the smaller box before it.

Comment: Thanks for your post, but it doesnt solve to problem, the boxes does not fill the space. for example two small boxes show go over each other. like the picture